# Can I always write a bounded operator $T$ as $T=R^{*}S$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $K$ and $H$ are Hilbert spaces and $T\in B(K)$, can I always express $T$ as a linear combination of products $R^{*}S$ for $R,S \in B(K,H)$ ?

I think I already showed this is true when $K$ and $H$ are finite dimensional. Is this true for any Hilbert spaces $K$ and $H$ ?

If it is not true, are linear combinations of such products at least dense in $B(K)$ ?

Comment: what does $R^{*}$ mean?

Comment: $R^{*}$ is the adjoint of $R$

Comment: If $H$ is separable, then every linear combination of such products $R^*S$ has separable image, and this is also true taking limits. Thus if $K$ is non-separable, the identity $id_K$ does not belong to the closure of the linear span of such products.

Comment: I am assuming H and K are separable.

Answer (score 1):

**Construction**

Suppose one has:
$$\dim\mathcal{H}\geq\dim\mathcal{K}$$

Remember the unitaries:
$$\#S=\dim\mathcal{H}:\quad U_\mathcal{H}(\varphi):=(\langle \sigma_s,\varphi\rangle)_{s\in S}\in\ell^2(S)$$
$$\#T=\dim\mathcal{H}:\quad U_\mathcal{K}(\psi):=(\langle \tau_t,\varphi\rangle)_{t\in T}\in\ell^2(T)$$

Regard an embedding:
$$\iota:T\hookrightarrow S:\quad (Ex)_{s=\iota(t)}:=x_t\quad(Ex)_{s\neq\iota(t)}:=0$$

Then one obtains:
$$J:=U_\mathcal{H}^{-1}\circ E\circ U_\mathcal{K}:\quad J^*J=1_\mathcal{K}$$

Construct operators:
$$R^*L:=(JT^*)^*J=TJ^*J=T$$

Concluding construction:

**Counterexample**

Given the Hilbert spaces $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Consider the operator:
$$T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}^2):\quad T:=1_{\mathbb{C}^2}$$

Then this fails since:
$$\dim\mathcal{R}R^*L\leq\dim\mathcal{R}R^*\leq1\\
<2=\dim\mathcal{R}1_{\mathbb{C}^2}=\dim\mathcal{R}T$$

Concluding counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am assuming $K,H \neq 0$

Comment: Then it still fails: The problem remains as one loses degree of freedom one traversing through a smaller space.

Comment: Do you have an example? Remember  my question is allowing linear combinations of these products. So for example for finite dimensional $H$ and $K$, I can produce each element of the matrix basis for $B(K)$ with these products, hence getting any element in B(K) when I take linear combinations.

Comment: Wait a second..

Comment: Ok have a look at the argument.

Comment: Ah for sums its a different story: That always works! *(As long one works with arbitrary sums of projections.)*

Comment: It depends on the topology on $B(K)$ if the sums of operators of the form $R^\ast S$ are dense. If $K$ is infinite-dimensional and $H$ finite-dimensional, all the operators $R^\ast S$ have finite rank and the norm-closure of their linear span is therefore contained in the space of all compact operators, a proper subspace of $B(K)$.

Comment: I am interested in denseness in the $w^{*}$ topology of $B(K)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $K$ and $H$, I can write any $T$ as a linear combination of these products, then by Goldstine's Theorem, these linear combinations are $w^{*}$ dense in $B(K)$.